# BeautifulSoup not Finding Elements in Dev Tools

Tags: python, html, beautifulsoup

I'm trying to scrape some data off of [this website](https://www.oddsportal.com/rugby-union/france/pro-d2/results/), but it seems like I'm unable to find anything... all of the variables that I try to store `soup.select` or `soup.find_all`s to are null

When I just print `soup` it doesn't include and of these classes that I'm trying to find either, so I'm wondering if I'm missing something fundamental?

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests

url = 'https://www.oddsportal.com/rugby-union/france/pro-d2/results/'
response = requests.get(url)
html = response.content

soup = BeautifulSoup(html, 'html.parser')
seasons = soup.find_all('ul', {'class': 'main-filter'}) # list of links for all seasons

# other things I've tried to find:

#total = soup.find_all('div', {'id': 'tournamentTable'})
#total = soup.select('#tournamentTable')
#league = soup.select('tr', {'class': 'dark center'})
#league = soup.select('body a')
#date = soup.find_all('tr', {'class': 'center nob-border'})
#match = soup.find_all('span[class*="deactivate"]')

#<a class="bfl sicona s8" href="/rugby-union/">Rugby Union</a>

print(seasons)
#print(total)
#print(league)
#print(date)
#print(match)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That's a js rendered page. You need to use selenium to automate it. You don't need to manually install the chromedriver and then defining the path to the excecutable_path. you can use `webdriver_manage` module instead.

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options
from webdriver_manager.chrome import ChromeDriverManager

chrome_options = Options()
chrome_options.add_argument("--headless")
driver = webdriver.Chrome(ChromeDriverManager().install(), chrome_options=chrome_options)

url = 'https://www.oddsportal.com/rugby-union/france/pro-d2/results/'
driver.get(url)
html = driver.page_source
soup = BeautifulSoup(html, 'html.parser')
seasons = soup.find_all('ul', {'class': 'main-filter'}) # list of links for all 
print(seasons)
```

Comment: Thanks! I'm getting this error but I've installed selenium...
```
from webdriver_manager.chrome import ChromeDriverManager
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'webdriver_manager'
```

Comment: EDIT: I think I have it working now with
```
from webdriver_manager.chrome import ChromeDriverManager
```

Answer (score 0):

It is simply because the data is loaded by javascript. consider using selenium

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
from selenium import webdriver

url = 'https://www.oddsportal.com/rugby-union/france/pro-d2/results/'

DRIVER_PATH="Your selenium chrome driver path"
driver = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path=DRIVER_PATH)
driver.get(url)

soup = BeautifulSoup(driver.page_source, 'html.parser')
driver.quit()
seasons = soup.find_all('ul', {'class': 'main-filter'}) # list of links for all seasons
print(seasons)
```